# SAML SSO QueryString is dropped

Tags: saml-2.0, pingfederate

I have SSO/SAML working without a query string in the URL: (https://yourURLHere.com/SiteA/ )

I have an issue when a user logs in with a URL that includes a querystring, the querystring is dropped during SSO redirect.  Does SSO/SAML  support URLs with querystrings? And/or is there another way to include a querystring at the end of the URL or some other way?
Example Query String:  https://yourURLHere.com/SiteA/go.aspx?u=/ch/zLAReq&Rid=24288

SAML Software: PingFederate Server

https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/ix_m_downloadDocumentation/page/ix_c_pingfederateServerDocumentationArchive.html

Comment: Where are you adding the URL as a query string? On the `startSSO.ping` application endpoint as `TARGET` or `TargetResource`?

Answer (score 2):

SAML doesn't really care about query strings of your desired resource, but it does have requirements on the various bindings. If you are passing a URL in the RelayState parameter in the POST binding, it will work just fine. If you're using RelayState in Redirect, you need to URL encode it.

PingFederate has some requirements around their use, and, when you think about it, it makes sense. If you are using the IdP Application Endpoint, you are feeding a number of query parameters to the endpoint, but primarily PartnerSpId. If you wish to use the `TARGET` or `TargetResource` (or `InErrorResource`) parameter, then as noted in the documentation, that parameter **must** be URL encoded. If you don't then Ping assumes that the `?` in your `https://yoururlhere.com/SiteA/go.aspx?u=/ch/zLAReq&Rid=24288` denotes the beginning of another set of query parameters, none of which does Ping recognize, and so it throws them away.

So, your "corrected" IdP application endpoint URL should look something like this:
`https://pfserver.domain.local/idp/startSSO.ping?
PartnerSpId=some:entity:id&
TargetResource=https%3A%2F%2FyourURLHere.com%2FSiteA%2Fgo.aspx%3Fu%3D%2Fch%2FzLAReq%26Rid%3D24288`

(**note**:line breaks added for clarity)

I should also note that the protocol endpoints of `/idp/SSO.saml2` and `/sp/ACS.saml2` for PingFederate expect **pure** protocol communication. Anything sent to those endpoints, e.g., an AuthnRequest to `/idp/SSO.saml2` or a response to `/sp/ACS.saml2` **must** be SAML2 compliant.

Comment: one can use  URLEncoder.encode(queryParams, "UTF-8") in java to encode params and append in base url.

Comment: @Nikhil - that doesn't pertain to what PingFederate expects or ASP code that OP mentions. I never really got a good answer though on what they were trying to do with PingFederate anyway - never responded to my request for clarification (not shocking).

Comment: hey Andrew what you said in your answer totaly make sense. I just commented a way to achieve encoding of targetResource.